# Write to existing json file

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I am using this code to add to my existing JSON file. However It completely overrides my JSON file and just puts one JSON object in it when I would just like to add another item to the list of items in my JSON file. How would I fix this?

```
Json::Value root;
    root[h]["userM"] = m;
    root[h]["userT"] = t;
    root[h]["userF"] = f;
    root[h]["userH"] = h;
    root[h]["userD"] = d;

    Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;
    std::unique_ptr<Json::StreamWriter> writer(builder.newStreamWriter());
    std::ofstream outputFileStream("messages.json");
    writer-> write(root, &outputFileStream);
```

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: Yes jsoncpp I cannot find any other way to do this Ive search for hours @drescherjm

Comment: I’d wager that pretty much every JSON library in existence only supports overriding the file, not doing in-place operation. In-place operations in a structured file simply don’t make much sense (in other words: it’s physically impossible). Any reason for not wanting to read the JSON file, edit the structure, and write it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is

- Load the file into a `Json::Value`
- Add or change whatever fields you want
- Overwrite the original file with the updated `Json::Value`

Doing this is going to be the least error-prone method, and it'll work quickly unless you have a very large `Json` file.

#### How to read in the entire file

This is pretty simple! We make the root, then just use the `>>` operator to read in the file.

```
Json::Value readFile(std::istream& file) {
    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;
    bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( file, root );
    if(not parsingSuccessful) {
        // Handle error case
    }
    return root; 
}
```

See [this documentation here](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/old.html) for more information

Comment: How does one load a file into a Json::Value then add to it like you say?